# Using jQuery Autocomplete w/ PHP, remote data source and categories

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having trouble implementing the categories feature of [jQuery's autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories).

Here's my script:

```
  $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
      },
      _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
          currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
          var li;
          if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
          if ( item.category ) {
            li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
          }
        });
      }
    }); 

    $( ".accountIdInput" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source: 'autocompleteAccount.php'
    });
  } );
```

And here's my code for autocompleteAccount.php:

```
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$sql        = " SELECT groupName,groupId 
                    FROM groups  
                    WHERE groupName 
                    LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' 
                    AND public = '1' 
                    ORDER BY groupName ASC";

    $result     = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));             

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $string = stripslashes($row['groupName']);
        $data[] = array("label" => $string,"category" => "Group");

    }           

    $newData = array_values($data);

    //return json data
    if(isset($newData)) {
        echo json_encode($newData);
    }
```

And the form:

```
<input type="text" id="accountQuery" class="form-control accountIdInput idInput formElement ui-autocomplete-input">
```

**EDIT:**
And a sample JSON output when running the php directly:

```
[{"label":"Test Account {12345678901}","category":"Group"},{"label":"* Test Group TEST {1234}","category":"Group"}]
```

No results pop up, but I'm not sure if it's because of how the JSON is being parsed (or isn't parsed) when returned. I've read other threads on the problem, but can't find any solutions that work.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the JSON results, it looks like `category` is always "Group". Also why not just pass `$data` back, why pass it through `array_values()`? It's just stripping off the keys which you're then trying to use in jQuery.

Comment: Your SQL Query is also vulnerable to **SQL Injection** as is. I would advise using MySQLi Prepare statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the SQL injection vulnerability. Regarding the category -- I'm just running a test at the moment, so everything is the same category. I was using array_values earlier to strip out keys to match the JSON output in the jQuery doc, but you're right it looks unnecessary. Removing it doesn't help, still no output even though it works on just the .php page.

Comment: Please provide an example of the JSON that is returned by PHP. Or add, `console.log(item)` to your `$.each()` to see what it's receiving in JS.

Comment: Added an example PHP output above. I tried adding the console log, but it didn't return anything.

Comment: Using your test data, I created the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ec6hL1tk/ This appears to work properly and does create the categories. This suggests that PHP is not returning the expected value. Please nvigate to your site page: `autocompleteAccount.php?term=te` and see what the results are showing. Maybe edit your post and include those results.

Comment: A deeper example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ec6hL1tk/6/

Comment: I'm trying your last fiddle verbatim, but I get a `POST http://localhost/echo/json/ 404 (Not Found)` error. I changed the URL to `url: "data.json"` and added an empty file by the same name and the error disappears, but no results show up.

Comment: You cannot use that code in your scripts, it is meant only to mimic an AJAX call to a remote element. Use your source, `source: 'autocompleteAccount.php'` in your script. Check your Dev Tools > Network and find the GET request and the response.

Comment: Looking at the Network I see the request but it just sits in "Pending" forever... no clue why?

Comment: So the GET request to autocompleteAccount.php never finishes; hence no results. Ok, can you navigate to the page directly, and add `?term=te` to it?

Comment: The PHP output works, but then when I try in the actual page it never finishes. After that, I have to restart my XAMPP apache to get the PHP to work again.

Comment: So it turns out there was an issue in the actual SQL query... I just started pulling out everything I could and finally found the issue lied in there. So sorry for that -- but thank you for the help!